# Model register save user created Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I'm using Django admin, and I have a model in which I have a created_user property. The problem is that I don't know how to register the user from the Django admin.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

In order to register the user who performed a create/update on a model in the django admin, override the save_model method in the admin view.

Assuming the model in question is **SomeRandomModel** defined as follows

```
#in models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class SomeRandomModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    another_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        blank=True, null=True, 
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by_set", 
        editable=False, 
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    updated_user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        blank=True, null=True, 
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_updated_by_set", 
        editable=False, 
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
```

To associate **created_user** and **updated_user** on **SomeRandomModel** with the current logged in user whenever a CRUD is performed in the Django admin, override the **save_model** method in admin.py as follows:

```
#admin.py
from models import SomeRandomModel
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(SomeRandomModel)
class SomeRandomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.pk:
            obj.created_user = request.user #user who created the object should only be set once
        obj.updated_user = request.user #user that last updated the object can be set on each save
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Reference: [How to associate model with current user while saving?](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/current_user.html)

Answer (score 0):

in On Admin Site you should see the automatically added `ModeAdmins` for `Users` and `Groups`

in `Users` `ModelAdmin` you can create new `User`.